# For an F# Type Provider, how do I make a relative path work as a static parameter?

Tags: msbuild, f#, type-providers

Is there a good way to make a relative path work for both the type provider while programming and msbuild while building?

```
//type AddressBookProto = Froto.Gen.ProtoGen< @"test\addressbook1.proto"> // VS GUI
//type AddressBookProto = Froto.Gen.ProtoGen< @"..\test\addressbook1.proto"> // Build
type AddressBookProto = Froto.Gen.ProtoGen< @"C:\Users\taggartc\froto\froto\test\addressbook1.proto">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `#if`

```
#if DEBUG //or similar constant
    type AddressBookProto = Froto.Gen.ProtoGen< @"test\addressbook1.proto">
#else
    type AddressBookProto = Froto.Gen.ProtoGen< @"..\test\addressbook1.proto">
#endif
```

Now you just need to define appropriate conditionals.